# Variation on Birthday Paradox Problem

Tags: probability, birthday

So, I have read the birthday paradox problem, and now I came across below question:

Assuming the following: there are no leap years, all years have $n = 365$ days and that people’s birthdays
are uniformly distributed across the $n$ days of the year.

(i) How many people must be there in a room before the probability that someone else has the same birthday as you do is at least $0.5$?

(ii) How many people must there be before the probability that at least two people have a birthday on 11th November is greater than $0.5$?

I think the answer to both of the parts must be $23$ people, as we are interested generally in only finding at least $2$ sets of people from $m$ people who have same birthday and then giving this probability.

Any corrections/suggestions/improvements on this is really welcomed. Please let me know whether I am correct?

Edit : Well, for both parts, let's say I have birthday on 11th Nov. Now if I want all people to have distinct birthdays other than that of mine so they can choose days from 364.

So, required probability model is :

$1-\frac{^{364}P_n}{365^n}$

For $n=23$, this works out to be 0.53 and Yes it seems to me I am done.

Comment: Well, for the second part, I say it's a trial with success rate $p=\frac{1}{365}$. How many trials must there be so that the probability of at least two successes is $>0.5$? If you have $n$ trials, the probability of $k$ successes is
$$
{n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
Then
$$
P(>2~\text{successes}) = 1- P(0~\text{successes}) - P(1~\text{success}) >0 
$$
and I get something like $n\approx 612$

Comment: What does "as you do" mean? Does this stand for an arbitrary but fixed birthday?

Comment: @SK19-that means say I have my birthday on 12 Nov. Now how many people I need to say that probability that someone else has same birthday as me is at least 0.5?

Comment: @Matti-Why do we have to use Binomial distribution here? Is each trial independent of the other one?

Comment: 183, for the first question

Comment: 548 for the second question